# I am getting post method not allowed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])    
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    contact = ContactMe.objects.all()
    serializer = ContactMeSerializer(contact, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=True)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = ContactMeSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

I am getting post method not allowed, i don't know why i keep getting post method not allowed. The source code is below. Thanks

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ListingView, SearchView, ListingsView, contact


urlpatterns = [
    path('contact/', contact)
]
```

Comment: Is your actual code properly indented (the if/else block in the contact view)?

Comment: @PaulKuhle It's properly indented

Comment: Can you show me the error message?

Comment: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="api"

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}

Comment: On chrome, xhr.js:220 
        
      
        
        
      
        
      
       
        
       POST http://localhost:8000/api/listings/contact-me/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: What is the `api/listings/contact-me` url? Isn't it `contact/`?

Comment: I have changed it, still the same. POST http://localhost:8000/api/listings/contact/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: @AdesiyanTope can you share main `urls`?

Comment: It is working now, I created a new app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not about `POST` method. It's the authentication problem.
You need to add the `permission_classes` decorator.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def contact(request):
    ...
```